# CoPrimes of Large Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

If I have Large Number, and I want to find all possible CoPrime numbers for it, including Large Numbers *above* it, inside a certain set...how do I do that?

I can only seem to find ways to find CoPrimes *below* it.

Is this because numbers above it will never be CoPrime?

Do I just check every number above it in the set, one by one?

Have I missed something important as to how CoPrime numbers work?

Comment: **Hint** $\  $ By Euclid $\, \gcd(n,a) = \gcd(n,a\bmod n)\ $ so the integers $a$ coprime to $n$ are precisely those whose remainders $\,a\bmod n\,$ are coprime to $n,\,$ e.g. $\, 1+3\Bbb Z,\,$ and $\,2+3\Bbb Z\,$ for $\,n = 3.\ $ You can use a sieve template with the  coprime remainders if you want to do it quickly.

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, the $s and multiple \s are confusing...what?

Comment: "above" means greater. How can you find infinite numbers?
It's impossible

Comment: Rafaele they could mean in a finite set ...

Comment: @Raffaele I think I specifically said above, but still within a limited range.  I.E. Over *n* but below *x*.

Comment: are they consecutive numbers in the set ,or not?

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee I should have been more specific. Given a range (x-y) I can find all CoPrimes of *n* where they are < *n*, but I can't seem to find CoPrimes that are > *n* but <x.

Comment: @ThatGuy That is MathJax code - see [the FAQ.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/117/242)  Apparently it is not rendering on your device.

Comment: @BillDubuque my thought is, it might be their browser doesn't support MathJax, or has something like JavaScript off that may affect it.

Comment: I have no idea what a MathJax is, and I do not think much of Java, so yes.

Comment: do you know modular arithmetic ?

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee I do.

Comment: @ThatGuy I said JavaScript a different language than Java. MathJax is a mathematical symbol making language, that allows pictures of math symbols in text.

Comment: All @BillDubuque was saying, is all numbers coprime to another number, are in the same remainder classes. Those classes that don't share a factor with the number.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee I dislike JS, as well.  It's an admittedly Luddite sort of bias, but after the drive-by days, I just never switched it back on... MathJax seems neat, tho.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee So, if I just factor all the numbers in a given range, any numbers that share factors are CoPrime?

Comment: No, any numbers that don't share a factor are coprime.  any numbers of form Nx+b where N is the number you talked about, x is integer and gcd(N,b)==1 is coprime to N.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee That actually helps a lot.  Thanks.